# SQL get number of columns in a particular row having a particular value

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, command, multiple-columns

I know that I can get the number of rows having a particular value in a particular column by making use of the COUNT(*) function, but I want to find the number of COLUMNS in a particular row that have a particular value. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I would have posted an example of what I've tried up till now, but I'm completely lost on this one...

Edit 1 - Here's some sample data and the expected result:

Table - trackbill | u1 | u1paid | u2 | u2paid | u3 | u3paid | u4 | u4paid | u5 | u5paid

So what I want to do is when I select a particular row using trackbill, I want to go through all of its columns and see which ones have the value 'false'. So if u1paid and u3paid were the only columns which had the value false, the answer returned should be 2.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?  It is also very helpful to see what you have tried.

Comment: I tried implementing COUNT(*), but I couldn't get it to count the number of columns, and when I searched online for help I found out that COUNT(*) can be used to calculate only the number of rows, not the number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider your table structure is as follows:

```
TABLE trackbill
( u1     NUMBER(10,2)
, u1paid VARCHAR(10)  -- contains values 'Yes' or 'No'
, u2     NUMBER(10,2)
, u2paid VARCHAR(10)  -- contains values 'Yes' or 'No'
, u3     NUMBER(10,2)
, u3paid VARCHAR(10)  -- contains values 'Yes' or 'No'
, u4     NUMBER(10,2)
, u4paid VARCHAR(30)  -- contains values 'Yes' or 'No'
, u5     NUMBER(10,2)
, u5paid VARCHAR(30)  -- contains values 'Yes' or 'No'
)
```

So, to check how many 'Yes's are for the `uxpaid` columns, we can write an SQL as:

```
SELECT u1, u1paid, u2, u2paid, u3, u3pai, u4, u4paid, u5, u5paid
       , CASE u1paid WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE u2paid WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE u3paid WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE u4paid WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE u5paid WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       AS no_of_paid_columns
  FROM trackbill
```

I can't help you with SQLite as I don't know it.

Comment: Your answer is the same, but better.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know. I was typing and when I clicked "Post Answer" I saw all these answers and got confused over which one is mine!

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are boolean, try to simply add the columns  So your count is u1paid + u2paid + u3paid + u4paid.  You may have to adjust that a bit, depending on syntax, but as long as the false entries are 0, it can be a way to get to your count.

If the columns are not bool, you can still do a compare on each field that returns a bool, depending on whether it has the value you are looking for, and then add those that are true.

Comment: You did post first, but the above answer was more detailed so I accepted that one. Thank you for your reply nonetheless!

Comment: The better answer should be accepted, not just who is first.  Which is why I gave it an upvote after I saw the other answers posted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to *unpivot* the data. You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to create a virtual table:

```
select trackbill,
  count(*) Total
from
(
  select t.trackbill,
    case c.col
      when 'u1paid' then u1paid
      when 'u2paid' then u2paid
      when 'u3paid' then u3paid
      when 'u4paid' then u4paid
      when 'u5paid' then u5paid
    end as data
  from yourtable t
  cross join
  (
    select 'u1paid' as col
    union all select 'u2paid'
    union all select 'u3paid'
    union all select 'u4paid'
    union all select 'u5paid'
  ) c
) src
where data = 'false'
group by trackbill
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/38507/4)

Answer (score 0):

You said you already knew how to do it if it was in a vertical format...

So here is your horizontal table made vertical:

```
SELECT Trackbill, u1paid FROM table
UNION
SELECT Trackbill, u2paid FROM table
UNION
SELECT Trackbill, u3paid FROM table
UNION
SELECT Trackbill, u4paid FROM table
UNION
SELECT Trackbill, u5paid FROM table
```

You can use that as a derived table to write another select on.