# To get number of columns with a specific value in one row

Tags: sql-server, count, multiple-columns

I have a table "Cinema" with Cinema_ID as my PK and all the seats as columns with data type bit (1 = booked, 0 = available) eg. Cinema_ID, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, ..., E5. Is it possible to only count the columns with a row value of 1?

Comment: It will be much easier if you normalize your table into Third normal form (transform all the columns A1..En into one column seat).

Comment: Thanx for commenting so quick. I did that the first time where i had a table "Seating" but that only gives me more rows and an extra column "Booked" as I have 10 cinemas and if say A1 gets booked its booked for all 10 cinemas.. Will I really have to create 10 seating tables for each cinema..? Its for a 3rd year project at Uni and they dont want more that 5 tables. I already have 3..

Comment: The website connecting to the db has a seating chart and when clicked it books the seat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL get number of columns in a particular row having a particular value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417706/sql-get-number-of-columns-in-a-particular-row-having-a-particular-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides what @GriGrim says about the design you can convert the bit value to a number and then add the results:

```
SELECT ID, CONVERT(int, Bit1) + CONVERT(int, Bit2) + CONVERT(int, Bit3) BookedSeats FROM tblTemp
```

This will work because all bit values for `true` are represented as `1` and all values for `false` are `0`.

Of course with a large amount of seats this becomes almost unmaintainable, so if you have the freedom to normalize the design you should definitely go with this option.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 cinema_id,
 sum(case when A1=1 then 1 when A2=1 then 1 ... end) as counts from Cinema 
 group by cinema_id
```